# Font selection for colored text

Tags: rxvt

I'm trying to set the font of my urxvt terminal. It seems to be working fine for text with no colors, whereas colored text is displayed differently: [image: Non-colored text is showing fine]

As you can see the colored upper-case letters have the same height as the x-height of the non-colored text. What gives?

For reference the font-related properties I have in my .Xdefaults is:

```
URxvt.allow_bold:           true
URxvt*font: xft:source code pro:regular:pixelsize=18;hinting=True;antialias:True
URxvt*imFont: xft:source code pro:regular:pixelsize=18;hinting=True;antialias:True
URxvt*boldFont: xft:source code pro:semibold:pixelsize=18;hinting=True;antialias:True
URxvt*italicFont: xft:source code pro:italic:pixelsize=18;hinting=True;antialias:True
URxvt*boldItalicFont: xft:source code:semibold:italic:pixelsize=18;hinting=True;antialias:True
URxvt*letterSpace: -1
```

Comment: That's not just colored, that's colored *and* bold.

Comment: Ah indeed. I've changed all the fonts to be the same family now. Yet it persists.

Comment: @fredefox In that case, can you please update your post to include the actual contents of `.Xdefaults` after changing fonts to the same family?

Comment: Absolutely. I've added a few more options as well. See update.

Comment: The `boldItalicFont:` seems to have a typo: `xft:source code:` is missing the `pro`.